# Runtime error with Pytorch and num_workers

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader

Im trying to run this code in pycharm and is the pneumonia database from Kaggle

```
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
import torchmetrics
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def load_file(path):
    return np.load(path).astype(np.float32)

train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),  # Convert numpy array to tensor
                                    transforms.Normalize(0.49, 0.248),  # Use mean and std from preprocessing notebook
                                    transforms.RandomAffine( # Data Augmentation
                                        degrees=(-5, 5), translate=(0, 0.05), scale=(0.9, 1.1)),
                                        transforms.RandomResizedCrop((224, 224), scale=(0.35, 1))

])

val_transforms = transforms.Compose([
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),  # Convert numpy array to tensor
                                    transforms.Normalize([0.49], [0.248]),  # Use mean and std from preprocessing notebook
])


train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder(
    "Processed/train/",
    loader=load_file, extensions="npy", transform=train_transforms)

val_dataset = torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder(
    "Processed/val/",
    loader=load_file, extensions="npy", transform=val_transforms)

fig, axis = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(9, 9))
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        random_index = np.random.randint(0, 20000)
        x_ray, label = train_dataset[random_index]
        axis[i][j].imshow(x_ray[0], cmap="bone")
        axis[i][j].set_title(f"Label:{label}, id:{random_index}")
plt.show()

batch_size = 64#TODO
num_workers = 8# TODO

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers, shuffle=True, pin_memory = True)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers, shuffle=False, pin_memory = True)

print(f"There are {len(train_dataset)} train images and {len(val_dataset)} val images")

np.unique(train_dataset.targets, return_counts=True), np.unique(val_dataset.targets, return_counts=True)


class PneumoniaModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, weight=1):
        super().__init__()

        self.model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
        # change conv1 from 3 to 1 input channels
        self.model.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
        # change out_feature of the last fully connected layer (called fc in resnet18) from 1000 to 1
        self.model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1)

        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
        self.loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=torch.tensor([weight]))

        # simple accuracy computation
        self.train_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy()
        self.val_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy()

    def forward(self, data):
        pred = self.model(data)
        return pred

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x_ray, label = batch
        label = label.float()  # Convert label to float (just needed for loss computation)
        pred = self(x_ray)[:, 0]  # Prediction: Make sure prediction and label have same shape
        loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)  # Compute the loss

        # Log loss and batch accuracy
        self.log("Train Loss", loss)
        self.log("Step Train Acc", self.train_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred), label.int()))
        return loss

    def training_epoch_end(self, outs):
        # After one epoch compute the whole train_data accuracy
        self.log("Train Acc", self.train_acc.compute())

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        # Same steps as in the training_step
        x_ray, label = batch
        label = label.float()
        pred = self(x_ray)[:, 0]  # make sure prediction and label have same shape

        loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)

        # Log validation metrics
        self.log("Val Loss", loss)
        self.log("Step Val Acc", self.val_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred), label.int()))
        return loss

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outs):
        self.log("Val Acc", self.val_acc.compute())

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        # Caution! You always need to return a list here (just pack your optimizer into one :))
        return [self.optimizer]

model = PneumoniaModel()  # Instanciate the model

# Create the checkpoint callback
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    monitor='Val Acc',
    save_top_k=10,
    mode='max')

# Create the trainer
# Change the gpus parameter to the number of available gpus on your system. Use 0 for CPU training

gpus = 1 #TODO
trainer = pl.Trainer(gpus=gpus, logger=TensorBoardLogger(save_dir="./logs"), log_every_n_steps=1,
                     callbacks=checkpoint_callback,
                     max_epochs=35)

trainer.fit(model, train_loader, val_loader)
```

If I train the NN with num_workers set to 0, it works without problems but takes around 2 hrs to train, I have read that the number of workers can optimize the training but whenever I use a number bigger than one I get the next error.

RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

I have tried to create the if **name** == '**main**': at the end but is still giving me errors, any help?
Thank you

Comment: what OS are you using? specifying number of workers is only valid on linux based systems.

Comment: @Shir Im using windows 10 pro, there is no other way I can speed up the process then?

Comment: Training neural networks takes time, regardless of loading the data. You can try to use the `time` package to figure out what parts in your training process take time, I assume its actually the training process and not the loading of data.

Comment: Could you report the stack trace generated by the error?